Could not spawn process for application redmine-5.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
I upgraded debian 9 to debian 12, updated all packages. I need to update redmine 3.4.6 to redmine 5.1. I did everything according to the instructions, but when I open the ip address/redmine link, I get an error
The log file contains the following:
 [ E 2024-04-25 10:24:16.3733 576/Tk age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /opt/redmine/redmine-5.1: The application encountered the following error: Could not find rails-6.1.7.7, rouge-4.2.1, request_store-1.5.1, mini_mime-1.1.5, actionpack-xml_parser-2.0.1, roadie-rails-3.1.0, marcel-1.0.4, mail-2.8.1, nokogiri-1.15.6-x86_64-linux, i18n-1.14.4, rbpdf-1.21.3, addressable-2.8.6, csv-3.2.9, net-imap-0.3.7, net-pop-0.1.2, net-smtp-0.3.4, rexml-3.2.6, rotp-6.3.0, rqrcode-2.2.0, html-pipeline-2.13.2, sanitize-6.1.0, net-ldap-0.17.1, mini_magick-4.12.0, redcarpet-3.6.0, commonmarker-0.23.10, deckar01-task_list-2.3.2, pg-1.5.6, actioncable-6.1.7.7, actionmailbox-6.1.7.7, actionmailer-6.1.7.7, actionpack-6.1.7.7, actiontext-6.1.7.7, actionview-6.1.7.7, activejob-6.1.7.7, activemodel-6.1.7.7, activerecord-6.1.7.7, activestorage-6.1.7.7, activesupport-6.1.7.7, railties-6.1.7.7, sprockets-rails-3.4.2, rack-2.2.9, roadie-5.2.1, racc-1.7.3, concurrent-ruby-1.2.3, htmlentities-4.3.4, rbpdf-font-1.19.1, public_suffix-5.0.5, date-3.3.4, net-protocol-0.2.2, chunky_png-1.4.0, rqrcode_core-1.2.0, crass-1.0.6, nio4r-2.7.1, websocket-driver-0.7.6, rails-dom-testing-2.2.0, rack-test-2.1.0, rails-html-sanitizer-1.6.0, erubi-1.12.0, globalid-1.2.1, minitest-5.22.3, tzinfo-2.0.6, zeitwerk-2.6.13, method_source-1.1.0, rake-13.2.1, thor-1.3.1, sprockets-4.2.1, css_parser-1.17.1, timeout-0.4.1, loofah-2.22.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

I searched for information for a long time, but did not find a solution, it seems to me that after updating debian 9 to 12, the link to the gems changed, so now the application cannot open, it tries to find gems, but does not find any, although they are all installed and updated. Please tell me where the error may be, which way should I move?
ruby 3.2.4 (2024-04-23 revision af471c0e01) [x86_64-linux]

Gemfile.lock:
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.7.7)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.7)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.7)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.7.7)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.7)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.7)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.7)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.7)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.7)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.7.7)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.7)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.7)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.7)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.7)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.7.7)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.7)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.7)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actionpack-xml_parser (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    actiontext (6.1.7.7)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.7)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.7)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.7)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.7)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.7.7)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.7)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.7.7)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.7)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.7.7)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.7)
    activerecord (6.1.7.7)
      activemodel (= 6.1.7.7)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.7)
    activestorage (6.1.7.7)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.7)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.7)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.7)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.7)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (6.1.7.7)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.8.6)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    ast (2.4.2)
    base64 (0.2.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    capybara (3.40.0)
      addressable
      matrix
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.11)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    chunky_png (1.4.0)
    commonmarker (0.23.10)
    concurrent-ruby (1.2.3)
    crass (1.0.6)
    css_parser (1.17.1)
      addressable
    csv (3.2.9)
    date (3.3.4)
    deckar01-task_list (2.3.2)
      html-pipeline
    docile (1.4.0)
    erubi (1.12.0)
    ffi (1.16.3)
    globalid (1.2.1)
      activesupport (>= 6.1)
    html-pipeline (2.13.2)
      activesupport (>= 2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    i18n (1.14.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    json (2.7.2)
    language_server-protocol (3.17.0.3)
    listen (3.9.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.22.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.12.0)
    mail (2.8.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    marcel (1.0.4)
    matrix (0.4.2)
    method_source (1.1.0)
    mini_magick (4.12.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.5)
    minitest (5.22.3)
    mocha (2.2.0)
      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.5)
    net-imap (0.3.7)
      date
      net-protocol
    net-ldap (0.17.1)
    net-pop (0.1.2)
      net-protocol
    net-protocol (0.2.2)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.3.4)
      net-protocol
    nio4r (2.7.1)
    nokogiri (1.15.6-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    parallel (1.24.0)
    parser (3.3.0.5)
      ast (~> 2.4.1)
      racc
    pg (1.5.6)
    public_suffix (5.0.5)
    puma (6.4.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.7.3)
    rack (2.2.9)
    rack-test (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (6.1.7.7)
      actioncable (= 6.1.7.7)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.7.7)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.7.7)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.7)
      actiontext (= 6.1.7.7)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.7)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.7)
      activemodel (= 6.1.7.7)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.7)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.7)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.7)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.7.7)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
      minitest
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.6.0)
      loofah (~> 2.21)
      nokogiri (~> 1.14)
    railties (6.1.7.7)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.7)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.7)
      method_source
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rainbow (3.1.1)
    rake (13.2.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rbpdf (1.21.3)
      htmlentities
      rbpdf-font (~> 1.19.0)
    rbpdf-font (1.19.1)
    redcarpet (3.6.0)
    regexp_parser (2.9.0)
    request_store (1.5.1)
      rack (>= 1.4)
    rexml (3.2.6)
    roadie (5.2.1)
      css_parser (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.15)
    roadie-rails (3.1.0)
      railties (>= 5.1, < 8.0)
      roadie (~> 5.0)
    rotp (6.3.0)
    rouge (4.2.1)
    rqrcode (2.2.0)
      chunky_png (~> 1.0)
      rqrcode_core (~> 1.0)
    rqrcode_core (1.2.0)
    rubocop (1.57.2)
      json (~> 2.3)
      language_server-protocol (>= 3.17.0)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 3.2.2.4)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.8, < 3.0)
      rexml (>= 3.2.5, < 4.0)
      rubocop-ast (>= 1.28.1, < 2.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (>= 2.4.0, < 3.0)
    rubocop-ast (1.31.2)
      parser (>= 3.3.0.4)
    rubocop-performance (1.19.1)
      rubocop (>= 1.7.0, < 2.0)
      rubocop-ast (>= 0.4.0)
    rubocop-rails (2.22.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      rack (>= 1.1)
      rubocop (>= 1.33.0, < 2.0)
      rubocop-ast (>= 1.30.0, < 2.0)
    ruby-progressbar (1.13.0)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.5)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    sanitize (6.1.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.12.0)
    selenium-webdriver (4.20.0)
      base64 (~> 0.2)
      rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2, < 3.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    simplecov (0.22.0)
      docile (~> 1.1)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.11)
      simplecov_json_formatter (~> 0.1)
    simplecov-html (0.12.3)
    simplecov_json_formatter (0.1.4)
    sprockets (4.2.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (>= 2.2.4, < 4)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (1.3.1)
    timeout (0.4.1)
    tzinfo (2.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    unicode-display_width (2.5.0)
    websocket (1.2.10)
    websocket-driver (0.7.6)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    yard (0.9.36)
    zeitwerk (2.6.13)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  actionpack-xml_parser
  addressable
  capybara (>= 3.39)
  commonmarker (~> 0.23.8)
  csv (~> 3.2.6)
  deckar01-task_list (= 2.3.2)
  ffi
  html-pipeline (~> 2.13.2)
  i18n (~> 1.14.1)
  listen (~> 3.3)
  mail (~> 2.8.1)
  marcel
  mini_magick (~> 4.12.0)
  mini_mime (~> 1.1.0)
  mocha (>= 2.0.1)
  net-imap (~> 0.3.4)
  net-ldap (~> 0.17.0)
  net-pop (~> 0.1.2)
  net-smtp (~> 0.3.3)
  nokogiri (~> 1.15.2)
  pg (~> 1.5.3)
  puma
  rails (= 6.1.7.7)
  rails-dom-testing
  rbpdf (~> 1.21.3)
  redcarpet (~> 3.6.0)
  request_store (~> 1.5.0)
  rexml
  roadie-rails (~> 3.1.0)
  rotp (>= 5.0.0)
  rouge (~> 4.2.0)
  rqrcode
  rubocop (~> 1.57.0)
  rubocop-performance (~> 1.19.0)
  rubocop-rails (~> 2.22.1)
  rubyzip (~> 2.3.0)
  sanitize (~> 6.0)
  selenium-webdriver (>= 4.11.0)
  simplecov (~> 0.22.0)
  tzinfo-data
  yard

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.2.4p170

BUNDLED WITH
   2.4.19

